# Recognize Names using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I'm working on a problem and I'm not sure if Machine Learning would be an ideal candidate here.

I have a list locations along their alias. This is a supervised set of data that i plan on using to train the model. Using this I want to identify them in a list extracted from a large text corpus. The challenge is that the locations are foreign names so they are spelt in various ways.

**Training data**

> Name: Australia (AUS, Australea, down under)
>
> Name: Vienna (VNA, Jewel of europe)

**Corpus Data**

```
Austrea 
Country down south 
Oustralea 
the europe jewel
```

I am absolutely new at this so I would appreciate it if you could be descriptive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure on what you do but let's resume your task by the following:

- You have a big corpus you will parse
- For each line you want to find the **corresponding** location, according to your training data

The machine learning part will inspect what **corresponding** means. 
The point is to use a **metric** to evaluate, for each line of the corpus data, which location is most likely to be quoted. To do so, you can work on your training data, your corpus data, and, the metric that assess the connection between both.

**Training Data**

One way to work is to increase the information you have in your training set. For instance, to go from

> Name: Australia (AUS, Australea, down under)

to

> Name: Australie ([AUS, Australia], [austral, australia, australea, oustralia], [down under, country down south], [kangooros, Sydney, Canberra])

You noticed that now, arguments are gathered within groups (Of course, you can define yours), and each can be processed using Machine Learning techniques :

- International attributes: you can check the  [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) by scrapping the website, of you should be able to find a list.
- Different names of the country: scrap Google Translate to get a dictionnary of how Australia is written is every other languages
- Common denomination
- "classical" attributes
- ...

**Corpus Data**

Your corpus might be quite heterogeneous. Some pre-processing might be useful such as tokenizing them, so you might see that in a lot of languages, Australia always start with "austral" (do not forget to work with lowercases, unicode, no accent ...).

You can also remove the stopwords that do not provide any information "the", "a", ... Some libraries provides them (for Python, you can check BeautifulSoup) but in your case, you may want to customize them by hand.

**Metric**

This part defines how *close* (mathematically speaking, not geographically) are each corpus data to each location of the training data. Then you choose the *closer*

For each corpus data:

- You can check if the word(s) is (are) present in the training data
- Check if some words are synonyms `down under` and `down south`
- Use a similarity measure to evaluate the *proximity* with each location.
- Another way would be to train a Word2Vec with a corpus and to calculate the similarity with each training data - it is definitely more work as it needs some preprocessing, a well-choosen corpus, and a good similarity measure.

Finally, a good algorithm would mix these techniques and some more. There is a lot of preprocessing to do before using Machine Learning techniques but it's definitely doable by starting with a simple algorithm and improving each weak part.